# Master account to pay erc20 transfers

Tags: erc-20, gas

we are developing an exchange like binance and we have 10,000+ accounts. we need to transfer every erc20 balance from child accounts to our pool account and we need gas for transfer these tokens. is there a way that we can charge the gas from a master account instead of sending ether to child account for paying transfer gas?
thank you :)

Comment: Is transferFrom an Option? This should do what you asked for but needs allowance

Comment: unfurtunatly the approve method also needs ethereum...

Comment: If you reuse the addresses, you only need to pay once from each address to allow your main address many transactions

Comment: @Behrooz Payon the approve method is way cheaper and can only be set once (just give max approval)

Comment: the main problem of thic approach is we have to called approve once for each token and every time we add a new token we have to send ether and call this method for 10,000 accounts...